# Develop news application from Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, android, ios, wordpress, api

I made wordpress website. It is news website. Now I want to develop application for android and ios. So how can I do it? Instead of Webview which ways can I use? Also I want to send notifications when news added. Shortly I want to develop news app from Wordpress website like BBC News, CNBC etc.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really loaded with a lot of different topics.

First: Developing an android application can be done in a number of different ways, such as programming in any number of environments, or using a third party drag-and-drop type creation software. I recommend looking into different ways to create an application.

Second: If what you are looking for is your website working well on mobile, I think the easiest way to accomplish this would be to develop the mobile side of your website and create a notifications page where viewers could sign up to receive notifications upon new news hitting the site.

I hope this helps, and if you are in need of answers to more specific questions about aspects of creating an application I would be happy to help.

Comment: So the website is working well on mobile view. What you meant by looking into different ways of creating app?! And if so can I find tutorials related with this. I'm a little bit familiar with coding. And also I found something like json api or wp rewt api. I'd be wonder if you recommend the way I can develop it. Thank you for your reply)